# Отображение течения времени в ProgressBar

Tags: delphi

В общем идея в том, что программа запускается по истечении 10 сек, при этом есть окно приветствия.

Нужно, чтобы ProgressBar (Delphi 7 Timer ProgressBar) отображал истечение времени, после которого откроется основная форма. То есть, к примеру:

```
ProgressBar1.Max := 10;
ProgressBar1.Position := 1;
Timer.Interval:=10000;
```

Имеется ввиду, что одна позиция = одна секунда. Прошу помощи, "подсказок"... реализаций. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
ProgressBar1.Position := ProgressBar1.Position + 1;
if (ProgressBar1.Position = ProgressBar1.Max) then begin
  Timer1.Enabled := false;
  Form1.Hide;
  Form2.Show;
  end;
end;
```

Интервал = 1000, деления ProgressBar1 = 0..9. Больше ничего не менял из стандартного. Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

Почему  **Timer.Interval:=10;** ???

Интервал измеряется в миллисекундах,

т. е. 1000 = 1 сек.
В твоём случае нужно  10 000!

```
ProgressBar1.Max := 10000;
ProgressBar1.Position := 1000;
Timer1.Interval:=10000;
Timer2.Interval:=1000;
```

Самый пройстой способ с 2 таймерами (можно обойтись и 1,но придётся на мозги покапать):
1 таймер (основной),после завершения 10 сек, открывает окно и т. п.:

```
Form2.Show; //Открываем главное окно программы.
Timer2.Enabled:=false; // останавливаем 2 таймер!
```

Далее, таймер 2 (интервал = 1000 (1 сек)):

```
progressbar1.Position:= progressbar1.Position + 1000;
```

Comment: по моему вы не поняли вопрос..

Comment: Вам нужна инфа как сделать само окно приветствия?

Form1 пусть будет окном приветствия,а Form2 - сама программа.

Конец первого таймера: 

Form2.Show;
Form1.Close;

Comment: это ясно) 
Нужно, чтобы ProgressBar отображал истечение времени

Comment: Ааааа! Цифру?

Label1.Caption:= IntToStr (ProgressBar1.Position);